# No heads on my Venus flytrap

Tags: diagnosis

I planted some seeds a couple months back and they are doing really well but they haven’t even begun to grow heads I just have stalks and leaves I’m worried that I didn’t get what I ordered I have them in a mixture of peat moss and sand I water with rain water and the seeds are so tiny that I had to use tweezers

Comment: Hey there Wayne, welcome. It's common practice to post pictures so that people can see what you see. Can you post a picture of the growth so far? Were the seeds dark black?